Integral $\int\frac{\mu V-kv}{M-\mu t}dt$
Prove:$$\int\frac{\mu V-kv}{M-\mu t}dt=\frac{\mu V}{k}\left(1-{\left(1-\frac{\mu t}{M}\right)}^\frac{k}{\mu}\right)$$

Extra context (where the integral came from):
A rocket-driven car of total mass $M$ loses
mass at a constant rate $\mu$ per unit time at a constant ejection speed $V$ relative to the car. If the total resistance to motion is $kv$ when the speed is $v$.


Show that the acceleration of the car along a staight horizontal road is
$$\frac{\mu V-kv}{M-\mu t}$$
at time t from the start.



Hence show that the speed from rest is
$$\frac{\mu V}{k}\left(1-{\left(1-\frac{\mu t}{M}\right)}^\frac{k}{\mu}\right)$$


I understand how to obtain the expression for acceleration by:
$$F=\frac{d}{dt}(mv)=\lim_{\delta p,\delta t\to 0}\frac{\delta p}{\delta t}=\lim_{\delta p,\delta t\to 0}\frac{\delta m(v-V)+m(v+\delta v)-v(\delta m+m)}{\delta t}=\lim_{\delta p,\delta t\to 0}\frac{m\delta v-V\delta m}{\delta t}=-kv$$
$$\Rightarrow m\frac{dv}{dt}-V\frac{dm}{dt}=-kv \Rightarrow \frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{\mu V-kv}{M-\mu t}$$

But I do not understand how to integrate this expression in order to obtain the correct solution of the speed.

Rewrite your expression as$$\frac{dv}{\mu V-kv}=\frac{dt}{M-\mu t}$$
Now you integrate both sides. The left hand side limits are $0$ and $v$, the right hand side limits are $0$ and $t$. Can you take it from here?

yh thanks, I forgot abt that
